# Dropdown menu item moves other elements to the right

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation

I've been trying to create this basic menu from scratch but I've got a little problem: whenever I hover the 'Categories' menu for example(which is a dropdown element), the elements to the right get automatically moved even farther.

HTML:

```
<div id = "navbar">
    <ul>
        <li>News</li>
        <li>News</li>
        <li>News</li>
        <li>News</li>
        <li>Market</li>
        <li class = "navbar_multiple">&nbsp;&nbsp;Categories
            <ul>
                <li>Travel</li>
                <li>Entertainment</li>
                <li>Fun</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Fun</li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS: apparently too long - but included in the jsFiddle below

Here's the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ktvde9qo/4/

I want to make it so that when the user hovers over the 'Categories' item, it would create the dropdown menu under it but keep its dimension as it was. How can I do that?

Comment: Can't you reduce the width of dropdown??

Comment: I wouldn't do that, it would look pretty ugly. Here's how I would want it to look: `http://codepen.io/andornagy/full/xhiJH` (hover the Wordpress button)

Comment: when making such navigation its important you manipulate the most specific element which is the anchor tag at least, add a dummy anchor links to each nav menu and transfer all paddings to them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try the following approach using the following CSS:

```css
#navbar > ul > li
{
float: left;
margin-left: 21px;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #fff;
border-top: 2px solid transparent;
padding-top: 8px;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 1.5;
    height: 24px;
}

#navbar > ul > li > ul {
list-style: none;
position: absolute; /* change this */
margin-left: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
    margin-top: -5px; /* this can control the whitespace... */
}
```

Add `position: relative` to the `li` elements in your primary navigation, and add some line height and height values as needed.

For the secondary navigation, change position to `absolute` on the `ul` and tweak
the top margin to close any whitespace.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/adw5hp84/

By using absolute positioning of the secondary menus, you take them out of the flow of the main menu bar and you don't have to worry that the length of the labels will affect the primary navigation layout.

Note that there is probably more detailed work to be done on styling the spacing between links and so on.

Comment: nice one... also have a look at my answer, pretty much gives the same result but in a different way...

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `width` in `#navbar > ul > li.navbar_multiple:hover > ul > li`:

```css
#navbar > ul > li.navbar_multiple:hover > ul > li {
    display:block;
    height:20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

Updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ktvde9qo/11/

**EDIT**: To make all submenu items have the same width, simply remove (or comment out) the following lines, alternatively modify them for your needs:

```css
#navbar > ul > li > ul > li:first-child {
    margin-top: 8px;
    padding-top: 9px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/ktvde9qo/13/

**EDIT 2**: To make the submenu items longer than the main menu item, just add a longer width to the submenu item and a shorter one to the main:

The submenu item:

```
#navbar > ul > li > ul > li {
    padding-left: 0px;
    display: none;
    text-transform: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 4px 4px 8px 6px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid #39718e;
    background-color: #316885;
    width:200px; /* changed this */
}
```

The main menu item:

```
#navbar > ul > li.navbar_multiple {
    margin-left: 13px;
    width:100px; /* changed this */
}
```

Final fiddle update: http://jsfiddle.net/ktvde9qo/18/

Comment: It's better now, but now how can I edit the dropdown so all the items end at the same point?

Comment: Well what if I want the submenu items to have a width higher than the principal button?

Comment: updated my answer again... don't be afraid to just play with it, you'll get to where you want to be ;)

Comment: This solution works in an interesting way. By adding `width: 100px` to `li.navbar_multiple`, you have set the width of the parent container that is smaller than the width of the child element (secondary menu).  This causes an overflow condition, but since the overflow is visible, the secondary menu appears.  This approach also works well.  You would need some pretty subtle design requirement that would favor this approach versus one using absolute positioning.  In most cases, either approach will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it?

If contents will add in drop down list like Entertainment to  Entertaiment Daily Programs also this will be works

```
#navbar > ul > li > ul{
 width:150px;
}
```

Comment: bt worked for me. cay try with this also.  #navbar > ul > li > ul > li{
    min-height:20px;
    height:auto;
}

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like that:

**css**

```
#navbar {
height: 35px;
background-color: #4c9fcd;
position: relative;
top: 0px;
z-index: 1001;
}

#navbar > ul {
list-style: none;
text-align: left;
padding-left: 25px;
margin-top: 0px;
}

#navbar > ul > li
{
float: left;
margin-left: 21px;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #fff;
border-top: 2px solid transparent;
padding-top: 8px;
}

#navbar > ul > li:first-child {
margin-left: 0px;
}

#navbar > ul > li.navbar_multiple {
margin-left: 13px;
//padding-left: 5px;
}

#navbar > ul > li:hover {
border-top: 2px solid white;
cursor: pointer;
//background-color: #316885;
}

#navbar > ul > li > ul {
list-style: none;
position: relative;
margin-left: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
}

#navbar > ul > li > ul > li {
padding-left: 0px;
display: none;
text-transform: none;
font-size: 12px;
padding: 4px 4px 8px 6px;
padding-top: 10px;
border-top: 1px solid #39718e;
background-color: #316885;
}

#navbar > ul > li > ul > li:first-child {
margin-top: 8px;
padding-top: 9px
}

#navbar > ul > li > ul > li:last-child {
border-bottom: 3px solid #4c9fcd;
}

#navbar > ul > li.navbar_multiple:hover > ul > li {
display: block;
height:20px;
padding-left: 10px;
margin-left: 0px;
}

#navbar > ul > li.navbar_multiple > ul > li:hover {
background-color: #0d3f5a;
}

#navbar > ul > li.navbar_multiple:hover {
background-color: #316885;
padding-right: 0px !important;
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ktvde9qo/17/)